# Book where girl fights a evil sorcerer uncle who killed her father the king

Tags: story-identification, books, magic

I read a book review over 10 years ago; maybe 2003 -2004. I found it interesting and wanted to read the book but could not remember its name.

The story was about a princess whose uncle killed her father to usurp the throne. The uncle becomes a tyrant. He was a sorcerer or wizard because it said he transformed his enemies into "beasts". Naturally, the girl wanted to make things right. Any ideas?

Comment: do you remember anything about the cover of the book?

Comment: No, I never seen the cover. Just saw a review.

Comment: Do you remember where you read the review?

Comment: I believe it was someone's blog about fantasy novels.

Comment: Sounds like a fantasy version of *Hamlet* with a female lead (Hamlette?). No idea it is really is, but you might try searching based on that angle....